# Android: Gif doesn't fill screen

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw, gif

I have a gif that draws on a `Canvas` object using the `Movie` object. The gif has a resolution of 1920x1080 pixels however only fills about a quarter of the screen. How do I get it to expand to the screen, and why doesn't it already do this given that the size of the gif is 1920x1080?

Here is the code where I draw the gif and initialize the `Movie` object.

```
public SplashEnvironment(Context context, Activity act) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.act = act;

    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(+ R.drawable.resized);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    System.out.println(mMovie.width() + "x" + mMovie.height());
    System.out.println(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight());
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(canvas != null) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if(mMovieStart == 0)
            mMovieStart = now;
        if(mMovie != null) {
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if(dur == 0)
                dur = 3000;
            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have another question albeit less important. When I view the gif in windows, it is a much faster and smoother speed but when it draws on the phone it is much slower and choppier. Why is that and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the size - what you are actually displaying is a view, not the gif stream (you draw the stream into the canvas of this view). You need to make sure you've set the correct layout parameters for this view - the view probably has a wrong size.

Regarding the gif quality - I cannot tell you too much. It obviously depends on the rate at which 'draw' function is called. You can check out [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable), which should have better performance.